# how do you get request data within the new app directory?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I would like my nextjs13 app to serve content based on the subdomain / domain / slug / get_vars in the request.

I need to have access to the request data from within the new appfolder of nextjs 13, so that I can serve the right data on the server side.

e.g., sub-domain.my-domain.com/my-slug?my_var=1&another_var=2

How can I access the following data:

- subdomain
- domain
- slug (this I can achieve using a folder wrapped in [])
- get vars

Many thanks to any responders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Accessing domain & subdomain using `headers` function:**

```
import { headers } from 'next/headers'    

const Page = () => {
  const headersInstance = headers()
  const [subdomain, domain] = headersInstance.get('host').split('.')
    
  ...
}

export default Page
```

**Accessing slug through `params` prop:**

```
const Page = ({ params: { slug } }) => {
  console.log(slug)
  ...
}
 
export default Page
```

**Accessing query parameters through `searchParams` prop (server-components):**

Given sub-domain.my-domain.com/my-slug?my_var=1&another_var=2:

```
const Page = ({ searchParams }) => {
  console.log(searchParams) // Logs { my_var: '1', another_var: '2' }
  console.log(searchParams.my_var) // Logs 1
  console.log(searchParams.another_var) // Logs 2
  ...
}
 
export default Page
```

Comment: Thanks @ivanatias. Great answer. I'm new to nextjs and js frameworks - so it's taking a bit of getting my head around. I would normally keep my logic for getting data separate from the view but based on the basic video tutorials i've watched it appears that they seem to mix the logic with the view. How would you separate the above logic that would be needed on every page and the views or page/layout code. Thanks again, J

Comment: Well, I don't know the whole picture of what you're trying to implement, but solely based on the examples above, I don't think you have much to do/abstract in the last two examples, since you are getting that data through `props` and just using it. In the first one, I guess you could abstract that into a utility function that just retrieves and returns the domain and subdomain from the request headers.

Answer (score 1):

NextJS 13 has a new router API for params.

You can check the client component documentation for the following methods as they also give examples on how to use it for server side purposes:

- [useSearchParams](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-search-params)
- [useSelectedLayoutSegment](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-selected-layout-segment)
- [useSelectedLayoutSegments](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-selected-layout-segments)

Note that everything should be imported from `'next/navigation'` (it was from `'next/router'` before NextJS 13).

Regarding the domain and subdomain maybe the `'next/headers'` [documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/headers) can help you.